# Can't get the F# Word typeprovider to work for custom Word documents

Tags: f#, type-providers

I've downloaded the [FSharp 3 Sample Pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/) and tried out the sample for the Word documents typeprovider which works fine in the TestScript.fsx file when using the provided sample document (AA.docx). But when I try using it with a different Word document it doesn't work i.e. no properties are generated on the type provider instance (Person, MyCompany etc.). Even if I create a new document and copy the contents of AA.docx to it (keeping source formatting) it doesn't work. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The word type provider uses the Open xML API. The same word content can have different XML representation at backend. I'd suggest you to download the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and use the tool to visualize its content.